# Call method every time a controller method is ending

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a static class called NotificationManager and every time a controller method is called, I want to store the ModelErrors in the NotificationManager.

However, inside the NotificationManager, I can't access the ModelState because it is not inside the actual controller.

Is there any way to automatically call a method once a controller method is finished, without having to write it in every single controller method?

NOTE: I need to use the values in the view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Override the OnActionExecuted in your controller. You still have ViewData[]

```
protected override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
{
    //Do your stuff
    base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
}
```

Comment: this should work. Along with using `filterContext.Controller.ViewData.ModelState` to get the `ModelState` as requested by OP. Although better still to combine it with an `ActionFilter` as suggested by Slaks

Answer (score 4):

You can create a global ActionFilter and override `OnActionExecuted`.

Alternatively, you could put a child action in the view.

Answer (score 0):

You can override methods in the Controller class to do this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416513(v=vs.98).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.onactionexecuted(v=vs.98).aspx